# difficulty installing ruby ​on windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, rubyinstaller

after installing ruby ​​on my windows 10 machine, the same is not found when typing ruby ​​-v in the command prompt, what can i do?

I saw in the path if it had the variables and this one. I downloaded other previous versions and it also doesn't recognize it. I went to the control panel and it says it's installed.

Comment: Did you open a new command window to try running ruby?